# Image does not load in browser due to path

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to load this image in mt page but it is just an icon that loads.
here is the project path i am working on
E:\ESS\Trunk\APSS.src\lib\kiosk\src\adaptive\mobile\views\scanning_view.js

where should i put the image so that i can pecify the path

this is the header in dev tools:

Request URL: http://localhost/APSS.kiosk/img/kiosk/License_Sample.jpg
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Remote Address: [::1]:80
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

```
else {
            //vm.Src = "Driving-license.jpg";
            //vm.Src = "https://anyline.com/app/uploads/2021/07/arabic-ocr-id-scanning-2-920x517.jpg";
            vm.Src = "img/kiosk/License_Sample.jpg";
        }
```

Comment: What is the path to your web root? What is the path to the image?

Comment: E:\ESS\Trunk\ESS.App\src\img its the folder where image is holding , & the link i am working on http://localhost/APSS.kiosk/#kiosk/login/deviceId=HomeUser&apptID=e2e4f44c-1c11-4fc4-abb2-5b3ee70a006d

Comment: What is the path to your web root dir?

Comment: You can't link to a local file from a page loaded over HTTP. How you configure your HTTP server to serve the file (so you can link to an HTTP URL instead of a local file) depends on the HTTP server you are using.

Comment: if is use absolute path like i have commented out on the  code the image loads, i just want to use the image from project directory.

Comment: Request URL: http://localhost/APSS.kiosk/img/kiosk/License_Sample.jpg
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Remote Address: [::1]:80
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin